# Does bzip2 guarantee bitwise identical output for same input?

Tags: hash, bzip2

I'd like to provide hashes for compressed data but compression may be executed by different versions of bzip2. Does bzip2 or some bzip2 implementations guarantee bitwise identical output for the same input if called with the same compression level?